# Picking of rows and set NA in case of not found in R

Tags: r, rank

Following is the formatted dataframe named df.

```
Company     Category    Margin     Ranking
SBI             BK      34.5       1
PNB             BK      39.5       2
UCO BANK        BK      39.9       3 
BANK            BK      41.3       4
INDIAN BANK     BK      42.3       5
DENA BANK       BK      44.5       6
VIJAYA BANK     BK      44.5       7
UNION BANK      BK      47.6       8
CENTRAL BANK    BK      49.8       9
INFOSYS         IT      5.6        1
HCL TECH        IT      5.9        2
TCS             IT      6.9        3
CMC             IT      12.6       4
TECHMAHINDRA    IT      12.6       5
COGNIZANT       IT      15.8       6
IGATE           IT      22.4       7
WIPRO           IT      22.9       8
HEXAWARE        IT      34.8       9
MAHINDRA SATYAM IT      34.8       10
DR. REDDYS      PH      14.5       1
SUN PHARMA      PH      19.2       2
CIPLA           PH      23.9       3
LUPIN           PH      23.9       4
DIVIS LABS      PH      29         5
```

I would like to write a function **rankCompany()** that takes 2 parameters
(i)  a vector (a set of categories) and 
(ii) a rank (integer) as 2 parameters.

Output of a Function - Data.Frame (**df.out**)

**Content of df.out**

with a company name, category and margin that matches with the specified ranking.
In case, If any category does not have a company that matches the given ranking, then  should be returned under that column.

Below are the sample code to test the function.

**Test # 1**

```
catg <- c("BK", "IT", "PH")
rankCompany(catg, 2)
    Company          Category        Margin
BK  PNB              BK              39.5
IT  HCLTECH          IT              5.9
PH  SUN PHARMA       PH              19.2
```

**Test # 2**

```
catg <- c("BK", "IT", "PH")
rankCompany(catg, 7)
    Company          Category        Margin
BK  VIJAYA BANK      BK              44.5
IT  IGATE            IT              22.4
PH  <NA>             PH              <NA>
```

**Test # 3**

```
catg <- c("BK", "IT", "PH", "EG")
rankCompany(catg, 10)
    Company          Category        Margin
BK  <NA>             BK              <NA>
IT  MAHINDRA SATYAM  IT              34.8
PH  <NA>             PH              <NA>
EG  <NA>             EG              <NA>
```

Is there any simple way to  get this done?

Answer (score 7):

`merge` would be the function you should look into. Here's an example function:

```
rankCompany <- function(inDF = mydf, catg, ranking) {
  merge(inDF, data.frame(Category = catg, Ranking = ranking), all.y = TRUE)
}
```

Here are your "test cases".

```
test1 <- c("BK", "IT", "PH")
rankCompany(catg = test1, ranking = 2)
#   Category Ranking    Company Margin
# 1       BK       2        PNB   39.5
# 2       IT       2   HCL TECH    5.9
# 3       PH       2 SUN PHARMA   19.2

test2 <- c("BK", "IT", "PH")
rankCompany(catg = test2, ranking = 7)
#   Category Ranking     Company Margin
# 1       BK       7 VIJAYA BANK   44.5
# 2       IT       7       IGATE   22.4
# 3       PH       7        <NA>     NA

test3 <- c("BK", "IT", "PH", "EG")
rankCompany(catg = test3, ranking = 10)
#   Category Ranking         Company Margin
# 1       BK      10            <NA>     NA
# 2       IT      10 MAHINDRA SATYAM   34.8
# 3       PH      10            <NA>     NA
# 4       EG      10            <NA>     NA
```

---

#### Update

Having seen what you want with "worst", here's an alternative that is a bit better than your function for a few reasons (for instance, not hard-coding values into the body of the function as a start).

```
rankCompany <- function(inDF = mydf, catg, ranking) {
  if (ranking == "worst") {
    do.call(rbind, by(inDF, catg, tail, 1))
  } else {
    merge(inDF, data.frame(Category = catg, Ranking = ranking), all.y = TRUE)
  }
}

rankCompany(catg = mydf$Category, ranking = "worst")
#            Company Category Margin Ranking
# BK    CENTRAL BANK       BK   49.8       9
# IT MAHINDRA SATYAM       IT   34.8      10
# PH      DIVIS LABS       PH   29.0       5
```

---

For the convenience of others in the future, please share the `dput` of your data so that they can easily reproduce it. It should look something like this:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Company = structure(c(17L, 16L, 21L, 1L, 12L, 
    6L, 23L, 22L, 2L, 13L, 9L, 19L, 4L, 20L, 5L, 11L, 24L, 10L, 15L, 
    8L, 18L, 3L, 14L, 7L), .Label = c("BANK", "CENTRAL BANK", 
    "CIPLA", "CMC", "COGNIZANT", "DENA BANK", "DIVIS LABS", "DR. REDDYS", 
    "HCL TECH", "HEXAWARE", "IGATE", "INDIAN BANK", "INFOSYS", "LUPIN", 
    "MAHINDRA SATYAM", "PNB", "SBI", "SUN PHARMA", "TCS", "TECHMAHINDRA", 
    "UCO BANK", "UNION BANK", "VIJAYA BANK", "WIPRO"), class = "factor"), 
        Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
        .Label = c("BK", "IT", "PH"), class = "factor"), 
        Margin = c(34.5, 39.5, 39.9, 41.3, 42.3, 44.5, 44.5, 47.6, 49.8, 
        5.6, 5.9, 6.9, 12.6, 12.6, 15.8, 22.4, 22.9, 34.8, 34.8, 14.5, 
        19.2, 23.9, 23.9, 29), 
        Ranking = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
        5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), 
        .Names = c("Company", "Category", "Margin", "Ranking"), 
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Yes, It worked. Can you please explain the importance of all.y = TRUE parameter in the above piece of code.

Comment: Also, How to get the Companies list in each category with WORST ranking ?   Here WORST means the highest ranking in number.

Comment: @Kranti, the best way to learn is to try some things on your own. Remove `all.y = TRUE` and see what you get as a result. Also, read the help page for `?merge`. As to your follow-up question, I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: EDi,  I got answer to my requirement for WORST ranking as well.   As I have less reputation, I was not allowed to answer my own question for less than 8 hours.  I will post the detailed solution after couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution for this Question.

**This is the input dataframe**

```
inDF <- structure(list(Company = structure(c(17L, 16L, 21L, 1L, 12L, 
    6L, 23L, 22L, 2L, 13L, 9L, 19L, 4L, 20L, 5L, 11L, 24L, 10L, 15L, 
    8L, 18L, 3L, 14L, 7L), .Label = c("BANK", "CENTRAL BANK", 
    "CIPLA", "CMC", "COGNIZANT", "DENA BANK", "DIVIS LABS", "DR. REDDYS", 
    "HCL TECH", "HEXAWARE", "IGATE", "INDIAN BANK", "INFOSYS", "LUPIN", 
    "MAHINDRA SATYAM", "PNB", "SBI", "SUN PHARMA", "TCS", "TECHMAHINDRA", 
    "UCO BANK", "UNION BANK", "VIJAYA BANK", "WIPRO"), class = "factor"), 
        Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
        .Label = c("BK", "IT", "PH"), class = "factor"), 
        Margin = c(34.5, 39.5, 39.9, 41.3, 42.3, 44.5, 44.5, 47.6, 49.8, 
        5.6, 5.9, 6.9, 12.6, 12.6, 15.8, 22.4, 22.9, 34.8, 34.8, 14.5, 
        19.2, 23.9, 23.9, 29), 
        Ranking = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
        5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), 
        .Names = c("Company", "Category", "Margin", "Ranking"), 
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

**Input Dataset looks like the following**

```
> mydf
           Company Category Margin Ranking
1              SBI       BK   34.5       1
2              PNB       BK   39.5       2
3         UCO BANK       BK   39.9       3
4             BANK       BK   41.3       4
5      INDIAN BANK       BK   42.3       5
6        DENA BANK       BK   44.5       6
7      VIJAYA BANK       BK   44.5       7
8       UNION BANK       BK   47.6       8
9     CENTRAL BANK       BK   49.8       9
10         INFOSYS       IT    5.6       1
11        HCL TECH       IT    5.9       2
12             TCS       IT    6.9       3
13             CMC       IT   12.6       4
14    TECHMAHINDRA       IT   12.6       5
15       COGNIZANT       IT   15.8       6
16           IGATE       IT   22.4       7
17           WIPRO       IT   22.9       8
18        HEXAWARE       IT   34.8       9
19 MAHINDRA SATYAM       IT   34.8      10
20      DR. REDDYS       PH   14.5       1
21      SUN PHARMA       PH   19.2       2
22           CIPLA       PH   23.9       3
23           LUPIN       PH   23.9       4
24      DIVIS LABS       PH   29.0       5
```

**# Writing a function called "rankCompany"**

```
> rankCompany <- function(inDF = mydf, catg, ranking) {
   if (ranking == "worst") {
      worst.ranks <- as.vector(table(inDF$Category))
      mgdf <- merge(inDF, data.frame(Category = catg, Ranking = worst.ranks), all.y = TRUE)
   } else if(is.numeric(ranking)) {
      mgdf <- merge(inDF, data.frame(Category = catg, Ranking = ranking), all.y = TRUE)
   }
   rownames(mgdf) <- catg
   return(mgdf)
 }
```

**Testing the function :**

**Test case # 1**

```
test1 <- c("BK", "IT", "PH")
rankCompany(catg = test1, ranking = 2)
  Category Ranking    Company Margin
BK       BK       2        PNB   39.5
IT       IT       2   HCL TECH    5.9
PH       PH       2 SUN PHARMA   19.2
```

**Test case # 2**

```
test2 <- c("BK", "IT", "PH")
rankCompany(catg = test2, ranking = 7)
   Category Ranking     Company Margin
BK       BK       7 VIJAYA BANK   44.5
IT       IT       7       IGATE   22.4
PH       PH       7        <NA>     NA
```

**Test case # 3**

```
test3 <- c("BK", "IT", "PH", "EG")
rankCompany(catg = test3, ranking = 10)

   Category Ranking         Company Margin
BK       BK      10            <NA>     NA
IT       IT      10 MAHINDRA SATYAM   34.8
PH       PH      10            <NA>     NA
EG       EG      10            <NA>     NA
```

**Test case # 4**

```
test4 <- c("BK", "IT", "PH")
rankCompany(catg = test4, ranking = "worst")

   Category Ranking         Company Margin
BK       BK       9    CENTRAL BANK   49.8
IT       IT      10 MAHINDRA SATYAM   34.8
PH       PH       5      DIVIS LABS   29.0
```